# How to create a DLQ on another existing DLQ and set the redelivery policy etc?

Tags: activemq-classic

The problem statement requires to read messages from an existing DLQ and define a redelivery policy on the DLQ to create DLQ for the existing one.

public class DLQonDLQ {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

```
      ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"); 
      ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection("admin","admin");

      RedeliveryPolicy policy = connection.getRedeliveryPolicy();

      policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(500);
      policy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);
      policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
      policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(2);

      Session session = connection.createSession(true, 0);

      Queue queue = session.createQueue("DLQ.exampleQueue");

      MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

      connection.start();

      TextMessage messageReceived = (TextMessage) messageConsumer.receive(5000);
      System.out.println("1st delivery from " + queue.getQueueName() + ": " + messageReceived.getText());
      session.rollback();
```

Comment: And what have you done so far to solve the stated problem?

Comment: I am creating a scenario on the existing DLQ such that the maximum redelivery count is 3. After 3 retries, the messages from the DLQ are lost, however, a new DLQ on the existing DLQ isn't created.
Please check the updated question description for the code.